# kubernetes HPA deleted automatically

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-hpa

I wanted to setup HPA for a deployment on my kubernetes cluster (1.14.0 on bare metal) so I followed the instructions to setup metrics-server here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server.

After deploying metrics-server, I am able issue commands like `kubectl top nodes` and deploy HPA's using `kubectl autoscale deployment <deployment-name> --min=1 ...`

Currently, the issue I am facing is the HPA's created from `kubectl autoscale ...` seem to be deleted automatically for some reason after around 4-5 mins. So, I feel like there is some important information/step I am missing related to HPA on kubernetes? But I couldn't find any further information related to this particular issue when searching online...

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Could the deletion be part of a scale down activity?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I don't think so. At least, nothing I explicitly setup.

Comment: The HorizontalPodAutoscaler resources get deleted? So when you do `kubectl get hpa`, it's not there anymore?

Comment: @weibeld Yup, I am monitoring it using "watch kubectl get hpa" and they seem to be deleted around 4min after they are created

Comment: Is your k8s cluster deployed with `kubeadm` ? If yes and `kube-apiserver` is deployed as a `pod` you can try `kubectl logs -n kube-system kube-apiserver`. There should be some information regarding creation and removal of `hpa` resource there.